# Possibly a bug: semicolon in strings

Tags: autohotkey

This line results in an error message:
`MsgBox "I can haz semicolon? ; No!"`

AHK Complains about a missing quotation mark. Apparently it stops parsing at the semicolon.

Escaping the semicolon helps somewhat: `MsgBox "I can haz semicolon? \; Yes!"`

But the result is that the backslash is included in the message.

Comment: This belongs on the bug tracker, not SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [escape character](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm) in AHK is the accent(`)

```
MsgBox "I can haz semicolon? `; No!"
```

The [#EscapeChar](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_EscapeChar.htm) directive is not recommended (deprecated).